# JavaFX Application with SwingNode doesn't maximise properly on some machines

Tags: java, javafx-8, repaint, maximize-window

I have a slightly complicated JavaFX GUI with the following component structure (simplified) as shown below. You will see that a SwingNode is used to contain the main bulk of the application, but I cannot tell you the design principle behind this since I didn't write the original code.

I am aware of various cautions about occasional odd behaviour when Swing & JavaFX are mixed, but there isn't the time at present to re-write the UI. The application is built to run on a Windows 7/8/10 platform, and what I'm seeing is as follows:

(a) On three different platforms I've tested (Windows XP native, Windows 7 VM, Windows 8 VM, different size monitors), when the application's Windows "maximize" decoration is clicked, the application resizes OK (by which I mean it is slightly jumpy and delayed, but the actual repainting to fill the screen is done correctly).

(b) However, on one further platform, the 'maximize' causes the entire content of the Stage to go white, and doesn't repaint properly until, say, a menu or one of its items is clicked. The machine in question is a Dell Optiplex 64-bit Windows 7 Pro SP1 with a DVI monitor of 1920 x 1080 sourced from an Intel HD Graphics 4600. ClearType is set to ON, and the version of Java is 1.8.0_73_b02.

There is one further question on SO regarding this issue, but it was created in June 2015 and never answered, so I'm not sure what to think.

Has anyone else come across this issue and/or feels able to comment on what might be causing it ? Is there some sort of 'revalidate/repaint' code, or JavaFX equivalent, which might be worth me trying as a workaround ?

```
public class Main extends Application
{   
    private SwingNode mainSwingNode = new SwingNode();
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        BorderPane parent = new BorderPane(mainSwingNode);
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 1024, 768);
        // Build Swing components
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            createAndShowGUI();
            mainSwingNode.setContent(mainPanel);
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Setup canvas area & canvas rulers    
        mCanvasTabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        mainPanel.add(mCanvasTabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        menubar.initForActionsMap(menuActionsMap);
        // Listen for property changes for site to enable/disable menus
        ProjSingleton.getInstance().addPropertyChangeListener(menubar);
        mainPanel.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Setup show/hide sidebar button
        btnShowSidebar = new JButton(menuActionsMap.get(ShowSidebarAction.class));
        menubar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        menubar.add(btnShowSidebar);
        btnShowSidebar.setOpaque(false);
        btnShowSidebar.setAlignmentX(JComponent.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        btnShowSidebar.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(2,2,2,2)));

        // Add site manager toolbar
        sidebar.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        sidebar.setAlignmentX(JComponent.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        sidebar.add(siteManagementPanel);
        sidebar.add(new JScrollPane(layerManagerView));

        mainPanel.add(sidebar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        Main.statusBar = new StatusBar();
        Main.statusBar.setCanvasTabbedPane(mCanvasTabbedPane);
        mainPanel.add(Main.statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```